# Django Rest Framework, using multiple model queries

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am quite new in using the REST Framework and I did not find in the tutorial how to achieve what I am looking for;

In my serialiser.py I have a class that is used to serialized MyUser models

```
class MyUserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = (
            'email',
            'first_name',
            'last_name'
        )
```

and in my view I am serializing a query that retrieve the user member in a team:

```
class EmployeeChartData(APIView):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []
    serializer_class = MyUserSerializer

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return self.serializer_class

    def get(self, request, format=None, *args, **kwargs):

        team_name_list2 = Project.objects.get(id=kwargs['pk1']).team_id.members.all()
        serializer=self.serializer_class
        team_name_data = serializer(team_name_list2, many=True)
        team_name_data = team_name_data.data

        data = {
        "team_name_list2":team_name_data,
        }
```

Which give me an output for example:

```
"team_name_list2": [
        {
            "email": "johndoe@gmail.com",
            "first_name": "John",
            "last_name": "Doe"
        },
```

My question is how can I add to that dict custom data and data from other models that are linked to MyUser Model.

For example I have a Team Model

```
class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default = '')
    team_hr_admin = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, blank=True, null=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(MyUser, related_name="members")
```

How can I add all the team that the specific user is linked to ?

Thx you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Read about Nested Serializer to give you clean code http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

2- Or Try this:

```
class MyUserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    team = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = (
            'email',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'team',
        )
    def get_team(self, obj):
        print(obj) # for you to understand what's happening
        teams = Team.objects.filter(member=obj)
        serialized_teams = TeamSerializer(teams,many=True)
        return serialized_teams.data
```

For your Team Serializer as follows

```
class TeamSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = (
            'team_name',
            'team_hr_admin',
            'members',  # you can exclude this field since it may seem duplicate
        )
```

For your view

```
class EmployeeChartData(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyUserSerializer
    permission_classes = []
    http_method_names = ['get',]
```

Comment: Hi thx for your answer ;) I got the error ("Creating a ModelSerializer without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute has been deprecated since 3.3.0, and is now disallowed. Add an explicit fields = '__all__' to the TeamSerializer serializer.",) . any idea ?

Comment: @Ben2pop typo in TeamSerializer, change field to fields

Comment: Yes I just figured it out :) thx you so much could you explain me why do we need to add : queryset = MyUser.objects.all() and http_method_names = ['get',] ?

Comment: On the queryset I used MyUser.objects.all() for I noticed you didn't perform any queryset for your MyUser serializer so my assumption was that you wanted all users records. You can do whatever suits you, for instance MyUser.objects.filter(first_name='John'), or if you want more customization like taking passed parameters from requests you can define & override "def list"  or "def retrieve" methods on your EmployeeCharData, in your case to get kwargs['pk1'].  as for http_method_names, you can removed or add whatever like ['get','post',] if you want to post data as well